# Properly transfer quote "stars should shine" into English

Tags: metaphors, quotes, russian

In Russian there is a sentence that can be directly translated as: "Stars should shine". But the nature of this statement means that talents should be exposed. Is it applicable in English to have this metaphoric sentence that talks about stars but implies talented people? Maybe there are better verbs, e.g. "glow"?

Comment: A rather old-fashioned English version is "Don't hide your light under a bushel", a reference to Matthew 5:15 in the King James Bible (where a bushel means a container used for measuring quantities of grain).

Comment: Further to @KateBunting's comment, there’s a song about that and the words are "Let it shine". The word "shine" applies very well to talents and although there might be other words for what stars do, when stars and talents overlap, "shine" is probably the best word.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing unusual about that sentence and meaning.

Comment: If I understood the reference correctly, it might be from Daniel 12:3: *Those who are wise will shine like the brightness of the heavens, and those who lead many to righteousness, like the stars for ever and ever.* (New International Version of the Bible)